# IF and Print statement incorrectly worded in Python

Tags: python

I am making a text game in Python. I need this to ONLY print "You cannot go that way, try a different direction" when the direction is not a valid move. But this is printing every time.

```
#show_game_instructions()
    while True:
    print('What direction do you want to go?')
    direction = input()
    current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
    print('You are in ' + current_room)

    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print('The item in this room is the', rooms[current_room]['item'])
        print('To add to to inventory: type "get" and the name of the item in this room')
    if direction not in rooms[current_room]:
        if direction != 'North''South''East''West':
            print("You cannot go that way, try a different direction')
```

Comment: You probably want `if direction != 'North''South''East''West'` to be something like `if direction.lower() not in ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west')`.  Hard to debug any further without seeing what `rooms` is though.

Comment: What is printing every time, but wasn't supposed to be printed?

Comment: `'North''South''East''West'` actually has the value `'NorthSouthEastWest'`, not what you expected. You can confirm this using the Python REPL or by printing it..

Comment: The location of that check is also highly suspect. You probably need the test for a valid room to come in between the `input()` line and the line where you change rooms with `current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]`.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/3KDJgEmuZ

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this line is not doing what you think it should do

```py
direction != 'North''South''East''West'
```

if you want to check that direction is not one of those options you could do

```py
if direction.lower() not in ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']:
    print("You cannot go that way, try a different direction')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the IF statement with this:

`if direction not in ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']:`